# How to populate a SELECT with OPTIONS from a JS object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following object:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var data = "[{"id":0,"class_arb":"آخر","class_eng":"Other"},
             {"id":1,"class_arb":"الإداريين","class_eng":"Management"},
             {"id":2,"class_arb":"المهندسين","class_eng":"Engineers"}]";
```

And I have a SELECT control in my HTML as follows

**HTML**

```
<SELECT id='class_id'></select>
```

Here is what I tried to populate the combo box:

**JQUERY**

```
$.each(data, function (id, class_arb, class_eng) {
       $('#class_id')
       .append($("<option></option>")
       .attr("value", id)
       .text(class_arb));
 });
```

The result I got is a combo box filled with 3 values, all of which display the text `[Object object]` and not the expected English or Arabic text as desired..

What am I doing wrong?

PS: the variable `data` can not be changed, since it is received from the server through an ajax call back.

Comment: This question means you have *not once* looked at your code with a debugger, and not once have you read the documentation of `$.each()` - because otherwise you would have known what the arguments of the inner function are. That's a bit of a shame.

Comment: @Tomalak I admit that I did not read the `$.each()` documentation. I was looking for a quick fix.

Comment: And you *seriously* believe that not reading even the most basic documentation is ok, as long as you are "looking for a quick fix"? You should be ashamed of yourself, if you're not too lazy for that, as well.

Comment: @Tomalak I also admit being ashamed. May I delete the question?

Comment: Questions that have answers can't be deleted. But look at the bright side, you're in good company, SO is full of questions like this.

Comment: @Tomalak I learned a good lesson today. Won't happen again, I promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at [jQuery.each](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function. It iterates over the entire array, giving you the complete row, but not its subsequent properties.

Change:

```
$.each(data, function (rowindex, datarow) {
       $('#class_id')
       .append($("<option></option>")
       .attr("value", datarow.id)
       .text(datarow.class_arb));
 });
```

find a working [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9409jg1t/)